# How to format C and reinstall windows?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, installation

I have two HDs that I wanted to format.

I have a backup of both, with all the important stuff, and I already formatted E, the external one, on its backup.

I have the installer of Windows (MediaCreationTool) and my password. I don't know much about it, but I think that's everything I need, so now I need to format C, the internal one. The problem is Windows is in there, can I just simply format it? And how do I install Windows back again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it, or you can run Setup from the Windows 10 ISO and start a repair install. At the appropriate time (watch the steps for the first while), elect "Keep Nothing" and you will get a fresh install and fresh user profiles.

This works well - I have done it.

The end result will be activated because Windows 10 was running on this machine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering but i'm not sure I understand what you mean by "running Setup from the Windows 10 ISO", could you please explain? I'm sorry for bothering.

Comment: If you made the ISO from the Media Creation Link  (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), you can insert the ISO in a USB port you can see it and SETUP.EXE is a file there.  Run it and that starts the Windows Repair and you can do a fresh install with this using the "Keep Nothing" option